# How to integrate JSON into Grails 4 (Gorm 7, Hibernate 5.4)?

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, jsonb

Grails 4.0.10, GORM 7.0.8 RELEASE, Hibernate 5.4, Postgresql 11

I have a "data" jsonb column in Postgres.  I have been trying to map that up through Hibernate/GORM.  To build.gradle I have added

```
  compile 'com.vladmihalcea:hibernate-types-52:2.17.3'
```

My Grails entity property has:

```
data type: 'jsonb', sqlType: 'jsonb'
```

At the moment I get a null property exception from 
com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.json.internal.JsonTypeDescriptor:

```
    public Object fromString(String string) {
        if (String.class.isAssignableFrom(propertyClass)) {
            return string;
        }
        return objectMapperWrapper.fromString(string, propertyType);
    }
```

In this case propertyClass and propertyType are both null.  In other words, the type declaration of the property is not mapped so that the JsonTypeDescriptor class sees it.  I have tried various hibernate annotations with @TypeDef and @Type.  The Grails documentation has this brief note on the column "type" descriptor:
"Hibernate also has the concept of custom UserType implementations. In this case you specify the UserType class."

No combination of declarations has worked for me; through all of this I cannot write a JSON string into the jsonb database column.  What is the correct solution?

Comment: I don't mean to make grails bad or anything, but maybe you should use Java for this entity instead as it clearly seems to be not working due to the use of Groovy? Alternatively, you could ask in the Grails Slack channel: https://grails.org/community.html

Comment: Very good points. I will first try the Slack channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using this, where the work was already done:

https://github.com/kaleidos/grails-postgresql-extensions

Comment: Added this to my project some time ago, and it was the solution.
compile 'org.grails.plugins:postgresql-extensions:7.0.0'